# Groß- und Kleinschreibung bei substantivierten Verben

Tags: verb, capitalization

Ich schreibe regelmäßig Aufzählungen von Aktivitäten, und komme jedes Mal ins Grübeln, ob es hier nun "normale Verben" sind, die kleingeschrieben werden, oder substantivierte Verben - wenn auch ohne Artikel - die großgeschrieben werden.

> Am 1. Januar: Beratung über irgendetwas, Erstellen eines Werkstücks, Löschen einer Diskette, Umkopieren einer Datei.

Wenn ich *"(das) Erstellen"* annehme, ist es ein substantiviertes Verb (mit weggelassenem Artikel) und damit groß zu schreiben. Wenn ich jedoch an *"laufen nach Wien"* denke ist es ein normales Verb und damit klein zu schreiben. Ich sehe hier den Wald vor lauter Bäumen nicht mehr, und bitte um Rat und Erklärung.

Comment: Wenn es Verben wären, hätte ich den passenden Fall und das Verb am Ende erwartet: eine Diskette löschen, eine Datei umkopieren, nach Wien laufen. Also sind es Substantive (mit folgendem Genitiv-Attribut).

Comment: Naja, ich habe mich bisher auch mit Umstellungen, Einzelsätzen, usw. aus der Misere gerettet und das Problem umgangen. Aber da der Beispielsatz von der Wortstellung auf jeden Fall richtig ist - ich möchte ja nur die Groß-/Kleinschreibung regeln - würde ich gerne bei genau dieser Satzstellung und Wortwahl bleiben :-) (Oder habe ich den Kommentar falsch interpretiert? Ich glaube fast, ja, also vielleicht umformulieren und als Antwort einstellen?!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wenn Infinitive ohne Artikel oder nähere Bestimmung stehen, ist oft nicht offensichtlich, ob es sich um einen verbalen Infinitiv (mit Kleinschreibung) oder um einen substantivierten Infinitiv (mit Großschreibung) handelt. Ein einigen Fällen kann sogar sowohl Groß- als auch Kleinschreibung gerechtfertigt sein.

Bei den Beispielen in der Frage handelt es sich jedoch um Infinitive, von denen ein Attribut im Genitiv oder mit *von* abhängt. Sie sind dadurch als Substantive gekennzeichnet und müssen gemäß § 57 b) des amtlichen Regelwerks großgeschrieben werden:

> Anwärmen und Schmieden einer Spitze
>
> Verlegen von Rohren
>
> Instandsetzen von 5 m Scheuerleiste

Auch Infinitive ohne Erweiterung sind substantiviert und werden somit großgeschrieben, wenn sie als illustrierende Beispiele zu einem substantivischen Bezugswort dienen:

> Hausarbeiten wie Putzen, Kochen und Waschen

(alle Beispiele aus Duden Band 9 – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch*)