# Groß-/Kleinschreibung bei Verben im Infinitiv

Tags: verb, spelling

> Aber hoffen und wissen sind zwei Paar Schuhe.

Schreibt man "hoffen" und "wissen" klein oder groß?

Comment: Similar: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/30038/392

Comment: danke schon mal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wie du willst.

Du kannst Artikel vor die beiden Wörter setzen, was bei normalen Verben nicht möglich ist. Daher kannst du argumentieren, dass es hier Substantive sind:

> Aber **das Hoffen** und **das Wissen** sind zwei Paar Schuhe.

Andererseits kann man die beiden Wörter im ursprünglichen Satz auch als Infinitive von Verben auffassen:

> Aber **etwas zu hoffen** und **etwas zu wissen** sind zwei Paar Schuhe.

Die beiden von mir genannten Varianten des ursprünglichen Satzes unterscheiden sich sehr geringfügig in der Bedeutung. Wichtig ist, dass der Originalsatz auf beide Varianten interpretiert werden kann, und je nach Interpretation sind die beiden Wörter mal groß und mal klein zu schreiben.

Wenn der Kontext eine der beiden Interpretationsmöglichkeiten vorgibt, muss sich die Schreibung danach richten. Allerdings wird es wegen der sehr ähnlichen Bedeutungen schwer sein, einen so klaren differenzierenden Kontext zu finden.

Klar sollte aber sein, dass es nicht zulässig ist, eines der beiden Wörter groß und das andere klein zu schreiben.

Comment: @Chieron: Vielen Dank, dass du genau das wiederholst, was ich in der Antwort geschrieben habe. Mir ist nur nicht ganz klar, warum du es wiederholt hast.

Comment: Mich würde interessieren, was du mit "...sie unterscheiden sich sehr geringfügig in der Bedeutung..." meinst. Ich sehe überhaupt keinen Bedeutungsunterschied.

Comment: @Chieron: Doch, eine Interpretation ist immer möglich. Du kannst dem Leser nicht vorschreiben, wie er etwas zu interpretieren hat. Die Interpretation hängt vom Kontext und von den Assoziationen des Lesers ab und lässt sich nicht durch Regeln vorgeschrieben. Werden nun die Wörter als Infinitiv interpretiert, so ist es zulässig sie klein zu schreiben. Tohubabohu hat in seiner Antwort die entsprechende Stelle aus den Duden-Rechtschreibregel zitiert.

Comment: @Tofro: »Das Hoffen« ist etwas wenig konkretes, etwas allumfassendes. Es ist so wenig fassbar wie »die Liebe«. Aber »etwas zu hoffen« oder »jemanden zu lieben« sind konkretere Ausdrücke, die etwas mehr greifbar sind. Ich gebe zu, die Unterschiede sind minimal und schwer zu finden, aber die Ausdrücke bedeuten eben nicht zu 100% ganz genau dasselbe.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Überzeugt mich leider nicht, aber +1 für den Versuch

Comment: Ich sehe ebenfalls einen Unterschied im Grad der Abstraktheit (stimme also Hubert zu).

Comment: Bin nicht bei euch - Vor allem hat @HubertSchölnast ein bisschen getrickst beim Antworten, indem er den Infinitivbeispielen ein Objekt gegeben hat und  den substantivierten Verben nicht - Trick entfernt, Gleichheit hergestellt: *Das Hoffen auf etwas* und *hoffen auf etwas* ist, genauso wie *Liebe zu jemandem* und *jemanden lieben* - finde ich - im Kern exakt dasselbe.

Answer (score 5):

Die [Duden-Rechtschreibregeln](http://www.duden.de/sites/default/files/downloads/amtliche_Regelungen.pdf) <sup>[**PDF**]</sup> fassen die hier geltenden Rechtschreibregeln wie folgt zusammen:

> **Regel 82:**
>
> 1. Als Substantive gebrauchte Infinitive (Grundformen) schreibt man groß <§ 57 (2)>.
>
>    das Rechnen, das Lesen, das Schreiben, [das] Verlegen von Rohren, im Sitzen und Liegen, für Hobeln und Einsetzen [der Türen], zum
>      Verwechseln ähnlich, lautes Schnarchen
>      das Zustandekommen, beim Kuchenbacken sein (vgl. Regel 49-55)
>      das In-den-Tag-hinein-Leben (vgl. Regel 27)
> 2. Infinitive ohne Artikel, Präposition oder nähere Bestimmung können in bestimmten Fällen entweder als Substantiv oder als Verb aufgefasst
>      und demnach groß- oder kleingeschrieben werden <§ 57 E3>.
>
>    ... weil Geben oder geben seliger denn Nehmen oder nehmen ist.
>      Wir lernen [das] Segeln oder [ein Boot] segeln.

Mangels vorangestelltem Artikel oder Pronomen gilt Nr. 2, so dass beide Schreibweisen zulässig sind. Die [amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) <sup>[**PDF**]</sup> scheinen mir hier zwar nicht zu hundert Prozent klar zu sein, denn sie führen in § 57 als Beispiel für eine Substantivierung (und damit für Großschreibung) an:

> **§ 57 Wörter anderer Wortarten schreibt man groß, wenn sie als Substantive
>   gebraucht werden (= Substantivierungen).**
>
> Man erkennt sie im Text an zumindest einem der folgenden Merkmale:
>
> a) an einem vorausgehenden Artikel (…);
>
> b) …;
>
> c)  an ihrer Funktion als kasusbestimmtes Satzglied oder
>       kasusbestimmtes Attribut.
>
> Siehe dazu folgende Beispiele:
>
> … Lesen und Schreiben (c) sind Kulturtechniken.

Das könnte man als obligatorische Großschreibung verstehen. Später liest man jedoch:

> E3: Gelegentlich ist bei einfachen Infinitiven Groß- oder Kleinschreibung
>   möglich, zum Beispiel: *Der Gehörgeschädigte lernt Sprechen.* (Wie: *Der
>   Gehörgeschädigte lernt das Sprechen/das deutliche Sprechen.*) Oder: *Der
>   Gehörgeschädigte lernt sprechen.* (Wie: *Der Gehörgeschädigte lernt deutlich
>   sprechen.*) (Ebenso:) *Bekanntlich ist Umlernen/umlernen schwieriger als
>   Dazulernen/dazulernen. Doch geht Probieren/probieren über Studieren/ studieren.*

Damit lässt auch das amtliche Regelwerk im konkreten Fall beide Schreibungen zu.

Comment: Dein letztes Beispiel: Müsste es (da es Infinitive sind) nicht regelgerecht bei den kleingeschriebenen Varianten *umzulernen* und *dazuzulernen* heissen?

Comment: Hmm - ich verstehe es so, dass "zu" kein zwingender Bestandteil des Infinitiv ist - eher eine Art "Infinitivzeiger". Aber das ist jetzt ganz "aus der hohlen Lamäng" geantwortet. Wahrscheinlich wäre das sogar eine eigene Frage wert...

Comment: Nachtrag: [grammis](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/termwb.ansicht?v_app=g&v_id=131) definiert den Infinitiv wie folgt: "Als Infinitiv bezeichnet man die unflektierte (Grund-) Form von Verben aller Art." [canoo.net](http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Finit-Infinit/Infinitiv.html) schreibt: "[Der Infinitiv] setzt sich aus dem Verbstamm und der Endung ?en oder ?n zusammen. " Ich verstehe das so, dass es sich bei dem Wort "umlernen" bzw. "Umlernen" um einen vollwertigen Infinitiv handelt, der aber im Satzgefüge unter Umständen mit "zu" ergänzt wird.

Comment: Ich glaube der letzte Absatz zum Infinitiv bei canoo.net (*der erweiterte Infinitiv als Subjekt* ist der Richtige: Da steht: Mach' doch, wie du willst. (Nennt aber in seinen Beispielen leider nur trennbare Verben)